# Is it possible to either loop running tasks in agent at build or release pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to loop running tasks in agent at build or release pipelines? 
like for-each from json file  we have list of blocks in json file 
for-each block i will start the running the task of the agent again

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398206/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-how-to-repeat-a-task  Does it sth what you need?

Comment: thank for your answer it work if you have template.yml and parse the Param from the azure_pipeline but in my case i have file json and i need to loop on it as array by each in yml can you help me ? like this in powerShell $MyFile = (Get-Content -Path 'DataFile.json') -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json >> foreach ($i in $myfile.data) { >> echo $i.nameicon >> }

Comment: It will be useful if you give ane example of json file.

Comment: {
     "Data":[
 {
   "nameIcon" :"VertexCart",
   "ArtifactNameAndroid": "MEShop-apk",
          "DistIcon" : "defaultIcon"  
  },

  {
   "nameIcon" :"bla bla",
          "ArtifactNameAndroid": "bla bla",
          "DistIcon" : "blabla"   
  }
 ]

}

Comment: i need a loop on this file like the power shell above but in yaml azure
i found "each" in yaml but i did not know how to use it in filejson and loop on it

Comment: my target of all this thing every block in the array Data in file json 
to build repeat a task every block with different values that i will get it from the file json

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to use for-each control to run tasks multiple times in your pipeline.

If you just want to run the tasks multiple times, you could simply add the task multiple times when using Classic UI pipeline or using template when using YAML pipeline.

For how to use template, kindly refer answer in this question: [Azure Devops YAML pipeline - how to repeat a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398206/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-how-to-repeat-a-task).

If you just want to use the loop to re-run/re-try failed task/step. This is also not supported at the moment.

There has been a related user voice.

> *Rerun failed build task/step*
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365697/rerun-failed-build-taskstep.html

Multiple persons commented and echoed. You could monitor the status of above user voice.

Comment: thank for your answer it work if you have template.yml and parse the Param from the azure_pipeline but in my case i have file json and i need to loop on it as array by each in yml can you help me ?
like this in powerShell 

$MyFile = (Get-Content -Path 'DataFile.json') -join "`n"  | ConvertFrom-Json
>> foreach ($i in $myfile.data) {
>> echo $i.nameicon
>> }