# Azure Devops YAML pipeline - how to repeat a task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my YAML pipeline I have a deployment job:

```
- stage: deployment_to_development
  jobs:
  - deployment: deployment_to_development
    displayName: Deploy to Development
    environment: Development
    variables:
    - template: migrate-vars.yml
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: migrate-data.yml
```

The deployment template is a simple DbUp task:

```
steps:
  - task: UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp@2
    displayName: Migrate data
    inputs:
      ConnectionString: 'Data Source=$(DatabaseServer);Initial Catalog=$(DatabaseName);Integrated Security=SSPI'
      ScriptPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\data-migrations'
      JournalSchemaName: dbo
      JournalTableName: _SchemaVersions
      LogScriptOutput: true
      IncludeSubfolders: true
      Order: FolderStructure
      TransactionStrategy: SingleTransaction
```

The variables template defines the server and db name:

```
variables:
   DatabaseServer: 'server'
   DatabaseName: 'dbName'
   Instances: '_1,_2'
```

This all works fine for a single database. However, I wish to repeat the task for each instance defined in the Instances variable, i.e for databases named dbName_1, dbName_2. This seemingly simple feat is proving difficult.

I have tried passing the instances as a parameter array and iterating them using

```
parameters:
  param: []

steps:
  - ${{each p in parameters.param}}:
```

but the 'p' variable isn't evaluated in the task.
There have been many more futile attempts. I must be missing something very obvious here. What is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't test `UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp@2` but I have sth what explain how you can achieve your goal. First define `template.yaml`

```yaml
parameters:
- name: 'instances'
  type: object
  default: {}
- name: 'server'
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- ${{ each instance in parameters.instances }}:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ instance }}
```

then reuse this template in your build:

```yaml
steps:
- template: template.yaml
  parameters:
    instances: 
    - test1
    - test2
    server: someServer
```

And here is the result:

[image: Azure DevOps Logs]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I learned something new about the structure of parameters there. I can replicate your response but appear to have broken my template which is now not firing at all in the deployment step. I shall keep tinkering.

Comment: Got this working now, thanks very much. I had originally tried with a parameter array as described in the question, but that did not work. I changed it to the format you detailed and wrapping the task in an 'each' block worked beautifully. Thanks again.